# How do I display a facebook app without the apps.facebook link

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook iframe app which opens properly with a link like `https://apps.facebook.com/<app_name>`
However I want it to open with a profile like `https://www.facebook.com/<name>/app_<app_id>`.
For example: https://www.facebook.com/inwi.ma/app_425874907457614

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is add this application as a page tab to gain accces to a URL like that.

More info on how to get started with your tab application can be found on Facebook's documentation - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Comment: I already tried that, but with pages, the link comes with a `pages/` name unlike that link.

Comment: Once you have a certain amount of "likes" on your page, you will be allowed to create whats called a "vanity URL".  That changes the URL of your page to a URL that is similar to what you are looking for - `https://facebook.com/VANITY_URL`.  Once you have that your URL will be how you desire - but you'll have to get those likes first! :)  I think you'll have to get 35 likes - but I'm not 100% sure...